# Xamarin.Forms net project

Tags: c#, android, winforms, sockets, xamarin

I'm still quite new to this and I don't know much. In general, I had a project on Windows Forms that received an image from another device using Net.Sockets and displayed it on the screen. I wanted to make it on Android using Xamarin and now I'm faced with two problems: `image.Source`cannot get the image from the Bitmap, the image will be extremely small, but I would like it to be full screen. How to do it?

Windows Forms:

```
private async void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var port = int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("port"));
    var client = new UdpClient(port);

    while (true)
    {
        var data = await client.ReceiveAsync();

        using (var ms = new MemoryStream(data.Buffer))
        {
            pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(ms);
        }
    }
}
```

Xamarin:

```
protected async override void OnAppearing()
{
    int port = 48654;
    var client = new UdpClient(port);
    var stack = new StackLayout();
    var image = new Xamarin.Forms.Image();

    while (true)
    {
        var data = await client.ReceiveAsync();

        using (var ms = new MemoryStream(data.Buffer))
        {
            image.Source = new Bitmap(ms);
        }
        stack.Children.Add(image);
        Content = stack;
    }
}
```

I tried to somehow convert the image into an array of bytes, did something with the Stream class - nothing came out - little experience and knowledge. Please tell me:)

Comment: Compare the size of the Form and the PictureBox.  The image should be scaled to the size of the PictureBox, but the PictureBox may not be the Full Size of the Form.

Comment: what exactly is in `data.Buffer` - is it a `byte[]`?  What format image data does it have - png, jpg, etc?

Comment: Yes, byte[]. Format - jpg, I think.

Comment: use `ImageSource.FromStream()`

Comment: Excuse me- how exactly?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66766026/xamarin-forms-byte-to-image-source-not-showing

Comment: And don't forget setting the Build action of image as Embedded resource and then you can convert this image into byte[], use byte[] for Image to render.